# Jquery and event register

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have

```
$(document).on('click','#my-butt', function(){
           console.log('document is always there');
        })
```

But I need #my-butt inside #myform ex:

```
$(document).on('click','#my-butt,#myForm' function(){
               console.log('document is always there');
            })
```

How can I do this without `#myForm > #my-butt` selector.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `'#myForm #my-butt'` ?

Comment: you need to remove `'` and `,` between `#my-butt` and `#myForm`. Space is required though!

Comment: As there is only one element with the id `my-butt` both selectors will yield in the same element O.o

Comment: Why do you need to change your selector at all?  What's the actual problem being addressed here?

Answer (score 2):

IDs should always be kept unique, so you shouldn't need to be worrying about whether or not an element with a given ID is nested within an element of another ID.

Also, there isn't really any need to be using $(document) in your function, ideally, the following should be complete enough:

```
$("#my-butt").on('click', function(){
       console.log('document is always there');
})
```

Comment: I am using name attribute .      $(document).on("change", "[name=KMS]","#timesheets_editorForm",function (e) {

Comment: `"there isn't really any need to be using $(document) in your function"` - Unless there is.  What if the `#my-butt` element is being dynamically added to the DOM after this code executes and relying on event delegation?

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos Please update your question to more accurately reflect your code :) Have you looked into using jQuery's find() function? :)

Comment: @David it is true